# C++ how to get a filed value from sql statment into variable

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am tring to run a "SELECT" command on an sql database and store the field into a variable through a "callback" function but I have now idea how to do that. Someone know what I need to add to my code so it will work?.

this is the relevant part of the code:

```
int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    // here I want to store the field value into the "data" variable so I will be able to use it later in the code.
    data = argv[0];
    std::cout << argv[0];
    return 0;
}

void DatabaseAccess::tagUserInPicture(const std::string& albumName, const std::string& pictureName, int userId)
{
    int* albumId = nullptr;
    int res = 0;
    std::string sqlCommand1 = "SELECT ID FROM ALBUMS WHERE NAME='" + albumName + "';";
    res = sqlite3_exec(this->db, sqlCommand1.c_str(), callback, &albumId, nullptr);
    std::cout << *albumId;
}
```

> the "tagUserInPicture" function working fine.

Comment: `data = argv[correct_column_index]`? What does the documentation or examples tell you?

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion, But still it's not working. can you take a second look on my code?

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you have *two* major problems:

1. The array `argv` is an array of *strings*, and you want an `int`.
2. You need to pass a pointer to an `int` variable, and then use dereference in the callback to access the original variable.

So to solve both these problems you need to change both functions like:

```
int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    // Cast data to the correct type, and dereference it to get
    // the variable it points to
    // Also convert the string to an integer
    *(int *) data = (int) strtol(argv[0], NULL, 10);

    return 0;
}

void DatabaseAccess::tagUserInPicture(const std::string& albumName, const std::string& pictureName, int userId)
{
    // Plain integer variable
    int albumId;

    int res = 0;
    std::string sqlCommand1 = "SELECT ID FROM ALBUMS WHERE NAME='" + albumName + "';";

    // Pass a pointer to the variable using the pointer-to
    // operator &
    res = sqlite3_exec(this->db, sqlCommand1.c_str(), callback,
                       &albumId, nullptr);

    // Since albumId is not a pointer, don't dereference it
    std::cout << albumId;
}
```